# How to generate barcode using Zxing as library in android

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I want to create an application to generate a barcode USing Zxing as library.
I want an barcode Image. I ahve used the following code im my main project.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.Intents.Encode"); 
intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT); 
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT", "CODE_128");  
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", "12345678912");
startActivity(intent);
```

But it is giving error:

```
10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.Intents.Encode pkg=com.google.zxing.client.android (has extras) }
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:672)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:747)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.check.MyFragment.onResume(MyFragment.java:62)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:891)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1053)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1371)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:418)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    10-04 12:54:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have declared activity in manifest also.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: how u resolved issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Î would say, you should declare the Encode Activity in your Manifest. Something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".encode.EncodeActivity"
          android:label="@string/share_name"
          android:stateNotNeeded="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <!-- This allows us to handle the Share button in Contacts. -->
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <!-- This allows us to handle sharing any plain text . -->
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you try to ship the ZXing Code in your App, please be aware that this could cause some odd behaviour in your App if a user has the normal ZXing App already installed.

Comment: More than odd -- it will pop up when another app trying to use Barcode Scanner invokes it. Not intended, and harmful to everyone. This is definitely not the solution.

Comment: And if more then one App on a Phone is using ZXing you could even switch from App to App. Imagine the opportunities :) And that's the reason, why I did a huge refactoring with my ZXing(Fork).

Comment: I don't quite understand this... there's nothing wrong with also implementing the same Intent API, if you're committed to implementing it. But that is plainly not the OPs intent, which is to be a caller and not implementor.

Comment: True, I take back my comment. However, the original question was also, why does my App crash when I call the ZXing Intent without declaring it in my Manifest. And the Answer to that is declare the Activities

Comment: @user1704369 Thanks... adding '.encode.EncodeActivity' in manifest did the trick.

Comment: But I have to remove intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);      to make it work.

Comment: @SeanOwen is this right method to do ? will it require barcode scanner should be installed in device ... i dnt want to install barcode scanner in device but want to encode text , email , url its doing this but failed to share  qr code generated from text

Answer (score 2):

This is quite confused. You are trying to use Intents (good, correct), but somehow also trying to add a bunch of code to your app (no need) and simultaneously trying to declare your app to be our app, Barcode Scanner (very wrong and harmful to us).

You do not need to change your manifest. Undo those changes right away, as right now, you are advertising yourself as our app from our namespace, and telling other apps you can respond to Intents for Barcode Scanner. Interfering with other apps this way is not going to go down well.

Remove all of the core and android code you copied into your project. You don't need it.

Instead, you need android-integration code, only.

Follow this:
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Except that you will call methods to encode a barcode, instead of scan.

Comment: I have simply added zxing as library in my project and only  calling it through Intents. Is this a wrong practice to call it using intents.

Comment: No, Intents are certainly the right way to go if you do not intend to write your own scanning app. But, that's not what you're doing. You don't add the app code to your app; it's not a library. Follow the link I sent you. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Answer (score 0):

Your intent action is wrong.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.Intents.Encode");
```

would be changed like

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
```

Try this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");

intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT", "CODE_128");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", "12345678901");

startActivity(intent);
```